# Speeding up compilation and unit testing in Visual Studio 2010 / Resharper / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, hardware

I'm working on a medium sized ASP.NET MVC solution with Visual Studio 2010 and Resharper. The project was blazing fast when I started developing it 1 1/2 years ago, but over time it has become slower - not only compilation, but also the time it takes ASP.NET to re-initialize the website. Since I am practicing TDD and refactoring quite often, I frequently need to recompile an re-run my tests, so I am looking for ways to mitigate this if any possible.

**The problem in detail**

It takes me about 20-25 seconds from starting to recompile the project to being able to view the result in a web browser.

Running a single unit test (just a single test, not the entire suite) with the Resharper test runner is also very slow (about 15-20 seconds). For some weird reason it seems that Resharper takes most of the time initializing the test run and spends only a very small fraction actually running the test.

**What I've already done:**

- Replaced my hard drive with an SSD (huge impact)
- Moved ASP.NET's compilation and the Windows Temp directory dir to SSD-like (hardware) RAM drive (big impact, but that was before SSD)
- Disabled automatic compilation of one project I rarely modify (Small impact since that project is small anyway).
- Weeded out unnecessary references to .NET and third party libraries (very small impact, if any)
- Some black magic tricks discussed in [this blog post](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx). (very small impact, if any).

Yet I am still stuck with the (slow?) figures above and I feel that this is harming my productivity. Now I am wondering what do do next.

**My current system setup:**

- Core 2 Quad Q6600 CPU
- 4GB DDR2 800 RAM
- 120 GB SSD
- Windows 7 x64
- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with Resharper 5.5

**My solution's specs:**

- 22.000 Lines of .NET 4 C# Code
- 3 projects: One ASP.NET MVC, one test project , one tiny general purpose library is included by the other two and which I do not compile unless something changed.
- 35 references to other libraries (.NET framework and open source stuff)
- ~200 Views
- 850 Unit Tests

**Now my questions:**

- Would upgrading my RAM to 8GB could give me a significant performance boost?
- Are these figures normal? Or perhaps this could be a problem with my solution?
- What would you try next (apart from buying an entirely new computer)?

Thanks,

Adrian

**Edit:** One particularly weird thing is that when I hit the "build solution" button, Visual Studio spends about 8 seconds showing me a waiting symbol until it actually starts compiling and the compilation window is being updated. The IDE is unrespsonsive during this period. Thats a good portion of the actual compilation time. I wonder what Visual Studio is doing during this period?

Comment: How many projects? How is the internal dependency state of the projects? If you re-run the same test does it take the same time?

Comment: Can you unload any projects at all?  This excludes them from the compilation process...

Comment: I've got a similar setup with 6Gb of RAM but without the SSD. VS2010 is painfully slow to load up and compile - I've found that disabling ReSharper has a very positive effect. Unfortunately, I've come to rely on this particular crutch...er...plug-in and have decided that the pain is probably worth it in my case.

Comment: Only 25 seconds?  Sounds like heaven!

Comment: I'd be interested to know what kind of performance gain each of the steps you've taken so far increased performance, if you're able to say.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: I can't offer any measurements with before / after figures, but I have added my subjective observations above.

Comment: @Jaime: 3 Projects, see my "solution's specs" above for details. Yes, it takes almost exactly the same time every time I recompile it.

Comment: @Brian: I've already unloaded what I don't need.

Comment: @Adrian: Thanks for the additional info!  Could I ask, what size did you set the RAM Disk to?  And how much of it is used?  Might try that myself, but don't have as much RAM as you...

Comment: @UpTheCreek: I have a hardare RAM drive (it's called an I-Ram, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-RAM) with 3GB capacity. It works like an SSD, but with actual DDR RAM on it, so it aways maxes out the SATA interface, no matter what is being loaded or written. Most importantly, it does not take away any of my real RAM. I put a 2 GB swap file plus various temp directories there.

Comment: @jfar: I'd like to express my deepest sympathy... ;)

Comment: @Adrian Grigore - 200k solution, 50 projects and my machine is faster than yours, SSD and everything.  :D

Answer (score 7):

For that size solution, it really seems that your hardware is ok and should be fast enough to build-test. What I've found is that most of the build performance problems (in my case anyway) are related to project dependencies and not to actual compile time. I couple of ideas to help you find out the problem:

1. try turning the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Diagnostic" (Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run), also install the VSCommands extensions (it contains a build statistics extension that shows time taken on each step) and check what is the part that is talking up the most time.
2. Are the dependencies on other projects (the 35 you refer to) in the GAC, or are they scatter through your HD? Are they auto-refresh references (do they have .refresh file underneath them). Maay try to simplify the resolution of these dependencies, ie copy local all the DLLs to the bin directory and see if it helps

Answer (score 3):

You can try the secret Resharper.Internal feature "Concurrent building with MSBuild" as described [here](http://www.hmemcpy.com/blog/2010/12/my-talk-at-the-alt-net-israel-tools-meetingresharpers-hidden-gems/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This is a well hidden gem indeed. Unfortunately it does not seem to work with my project (I just get some obscure errors along with some Resharper exceptions), but it might prove useful for future projects.

Comment: Looks like this option does not exist in Resharper 6.1 EAP.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an MVC project, ensure your project's "Build Views" is off.

1. Right Click Project File -> Unload Project on your MVC project
2. Right click Project File -> Edit Project
3. Check setting...
   false
4. Save and Right Click -> reload project.

I leave it on so that the compiler finds my mistakes before my customers do. But Build Views is horribly slow.

Comment: I already knew about this setting for a long time (even wrote a blog article about it once), but thanks for the hint. You are right, it does slow down the build. I use it only in release mode to ensure there are no typos in my source code in views.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Since I hit the `'Run tests'` button it took a minute or so to have the test running.

My problem was that I had the test settings pointing to `'Trace and Impact'` instead of `'Local'`.

To select test settings, go to `'Test'` menu and then `'Select Active Test Settings > Local'`.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a build server which will run:

- Build
- Tests
- Deployment

You'll have to wait roughly the same amount of time to see the new version go live, but it won't consume your development PC resources.

Comment: Yes, but I still wouldn't know what to do with the newly gained time. If it was a couple of minutes, I could read some blogs or browse SO, but 30 Seconds aren't enough to do anything worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here, I'd left 'code coverage' turned on.